# Query token balance before transferFrom

Tags: contract-development, balances

I am trying, but without luck, to query the token balance of the approver address before transferFrom event.

```
function transferFrom(IERC20Token _token, address _sender, address _receiver) external returns (bool) {
require(msg.sender == owner, "access denied");
uint256 amount = _token.allowance(_sender, address(this));
balance = _token.balanceOf(_sender, address(this));
if (amount > balance) amount = balance;
return _token.transferFrom(_sender, _receiver, amount);
```

}

Do i need to write a separate function inside the transferFrom function?

Comment: Function `balanceOf` takes a single input argument, not two of them.

Comment: Your attempt looks like a plain mistake of copy/pasting the previous line (replacing `allowance` with `balanceOf`). Also, you need to explain what "without luck" means (i.e., what problem exactly you're experiencing).

Comment: The problems is obvious, i can't compile the above code since its wrongly formatted.

Comment: So? What is the question for if the problem is obvious? Fix it and compile the code.

Comment: I am trying to query the token balance of the sender address before executing the transferFrom!

Comment: If i knew how to fix it i would not post my question here! @goodvibration, this is you being mean? :)

Comment: Not at all (being mean). But do you understand basic programming? You cannot call a function with whatever input you feel like. If the function takes a single input parameter, then you must call it with a single value. Here, you are calling function `balanceOf` with two input parameters, so it obviously doesn't compile. Not sure how else to explain that.

Comment: I'm only 17, trying to learn. I understood that it takes only 1 input, tried reformatting but i still can't compile. Its obvious that i was looking for a working example.

Comment: To put it simple - `_token.balanceOf(_sender);`.

Comment: ok, that worked! thank you. don't know how to approve your answer though

Comment: I'll write it down as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The ERC20 Standard](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-20) defines function `balanceOf` as follows:

```
function balanceOf(address _owner) public view returns (uint256)
```

As you can see, it takes a single input argument of type `address`.

In your code, however, you are attempting to call it with two input values:

```
balance = _token.balanceOf(_sender, address(this));
```

This cannot compile of course, and you need to get rid of one of them.

In other words, depending on your purpose, you need to do either this:

```
balance = _token.balanceOf(_sender);
```

Or this:

```
balance = _token.balanceOf(address(this));
```